# show Loading screen while component is loaded

Tags: angular

I want to show a scrolling img while the app-root component in index.html file is loaded.
If I place a text in that then the text is displayed immediately but img takes time to show.

```
<body>
    <app-root>

        <div class="load">
            Test load
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.load{
     background-image: path.
}
```

Comment: Well, because the image has to load too, and a text is lighter than an image ... I think you can't really have a solution here, try using an img tag maybe ?

Comment: you can take a look at this repo for the example 

https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/footballdetails/

Answer (score 2):

Be sure that your css rule for background is directly inside html file and not inside your css file which have to load too.

```
<app-root>
    <div style="background-image: url('')"></div>
</app-root>
```

And if your image isn't too big, you can convert it to base64 on website like [this](https://www.base64-image.de/) and add it directly like this:

```
background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhE...);
```

or

```
<img width="50" height="50" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhE..."/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using ngSwitch [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgSwitch-directive.html)

```
<div [ngSwitch]='status'>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'loading'">
        <!-- all of the inline styles and massive SVG markup for my spinner -->
    </div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'active'">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The part where the loading screen is taken care in my repo

```
 constructor(private router: Router,private _loadingSvc: LoadingAnimateService) {

        router.events.subscribe((event: RouterEvent) => {
          this.navigationInterceptor(event);
        });
      }


      // Shows and hides the loading spinner during RouterEvent changes
      navigationInterceptor(event: RouterEvent): void {
        if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
          this.loading = true;
          this._loadingSvc.setValue(true);// temporary solution to loading
        }
        if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
          this.loading = false;
          this._loadingSvc.setValue(false);//temporary solution to loading
        }

        // Set loading state to false in both of the below events to hide the spinner in case a request fails
        if (event instanceof NavigationCancel) {
          this.loading = false;
        }
        if (event instanceof NavigationError) {
          this.loading = false;
        }
      }
```

Html Template

```
<div *ngIf="loading">
            <!-- show something fancy here, here with Angular 2 Material's loading bar or circle -->
            <div class = "parent">
              <div class="spinner">
                <div class="rect1"></div>
                <div class="rect2"></div>
                <div class="rect3"></div>
                <div class="rect4"></div>
                <div class="rect5"></div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
```